# Initialising a variable in / as argument

Tags: c#, coding-style, initialization

Is a it common practice to initialise local variable in/as argument? 
For example:

```
Random random = new Random();

void DisplayRandomNumber(int myRandNum) {
   myRandNum = random.Next(10);
   Console.WriteLine(myRandNum);
}

public static void Main() {
   int randNum = 0;
   DisplayRandomNumber(randNum);
}
```

**Edit:** Someone taught me like this yesterday, still fresh in my mind. I don't think he had any intention to modify the value of `randNum` in `public static void Main() { // ... }`. Unfortunately, I didn't ask why because I thought this is a new style of coding.

Comment: Your sample does not probably show what you want to ask - value of `myRandNum` is not used and hence should be local variable of `DisplayRandomNumber`, not its parameter...

Comment: that doesn't initialize that argument. It overwrites it.

Comment: Are you asking if it's common practice to have `myRandNum` pass in to `DisplayRandomNumber` just to have it immediately overwritten with a new value? No, what's the point of that? Maybe you're thinking of using `ref myRandNum` so the value is passed back to the `Main` method where you called it?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I thought it was unusual too. Someone taught me a little coding yesterday, and he introduced me to this style. I didn't ask why.

Comment: Many would say that (unless the parameter is a reference parameter that is being deliberately changed so as to affect the calling scope) that it is bad practice to change a parameter's value even after having used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly valid code but the question would be why would you want to do that? It is definitely not common practice either. In your example you are only using the myRandNum in the method DisplayRandomNumber. There is no reason to have the variable outside of that method. What you have will be very confusing to others reading your code and will initially create extra variables that will never need to be used.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, method signatures can specify default values for parameters:

```
public void MyMethod(int myParameter = 5){ }
```

However, default values of parameters must be [compile-time constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  When the default value for a parameter is more complex than a compile-time constant, it is common to see code like this:

```
public void MyMethod(int? myParameter = null)
{
     myParameter = myParameter ?? myRandom.Next(10);
}
```

We use `null` to represent "no parameter specified", and then use [null coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to reassign the parameter.

More on named and optional arguments [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This code is valid because the parameter type is a struct, known in .NET parlance as a value type (being an `int`). If it was a class or a reference type, it wouldn't return back to the Main.

The other problem with it is it isn't very clear. C# has an `ref` parameter that makes it clear you're dealing with a reference argument

Instead:

```
Random random = new Random();

void GetNextRandomNumber(ref int random_number)
{
   random_number = random.Next(10);
}

public static void Main() {
   int randNum = 0;
   GetNextRandomNumber(ref randNum);
   Console.WriteLine(randNum); 
}
```

This will work whether the argument is either a struct or a class. There is also an `out` keyword, which is used in the various `DateTime.TryParse(string s, out DateTime date)` and `Dictionary<K, V>.TryGetValue(K key, out V value);`. The big difference between `ref` and `out` is that the compiler forces the `out` argument to be set in the method, even if it's `default(T)` for a generic type.